# C++/CLI create delegate for any event

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to expose .NET libraries to my company's products
by wrapping them in our custom JavaScript Engine. So far it's
been going rather well, but I ran into some problems when wrapping
.NET events.

It seems events in e.g C# can have very different delegates e.g.

```
public class Box
{
    public event EventHandler changeSize;
    public delegate void NameDelegate(string name);
    public event NameDelegate changeName;
}
```

And I would like to, if possible, support exposing them all to
the JavaScript engine. I managed to support specific events
using a helper class:

```
ref class DotNetEventHandler
{
public:
    DotNetEventHandler(DotNetObject *dotNetObj,
                       EcmaScript::GlobalObject *globalObj,
                       System::String^ eventType);

    ~DotNetEventHandler();

    // This method can handle events with the same signature, 
    // e.g. the Box::changeSize event in the prev. code sample
    void eventHandler(System::Object ^object, System::EventArgs^ args);

    void setDelegate(System::Delegate ^del) { m_delegate = del; }
    System::Delegate^ getDelegate() { return m_delegate; }

    EcmaScript::UString eventType();

private:
    DotNetObject *m_dotNetObj;
    EcmaScript::GlobalObject *m_globalObj;
    System::String^ m_eventType;
    System::Delegate^ m_delegate;
};
```

The event handler is then used as such:

```
void DotNetObject::AddEventListener(EcmaScript::Context& ctxt, const EcmaScript::UString& type, const EcmaScript::ValueRef& orListener, bool useCapture)
{
    try
    {
        System::Type^ objType = m_object->GetType();

        System::String^ eventType = gcnew System::String(type.c_str());
        auto eventInfo = objType->GetEvent(eventType);

        if(eventInfo != nullptr)
        {
            EcmaScript::GlobalObject *globalObj = dynamic_cast<EcmaScript::GlobalObject*>(ctxt.GlobalObject().SafeGlobalObjectPtr());
            auto eventHandler = gcnew DotNetEventHandler(this,globalObj, eventType);
            auto callback = eventHandler->GetType()->GetMethod("eventHandler");
            System::Delegate^ mdelegate = System::Delegate::CreateDelegate(eventInfo->EventHandlerType, eventHandler, callback);
            eventHandler->setDelegate(mdelegate);

            eventInfo->AddEventHandler(m_object, mdelegate);

            m_eventHandlers.push_back(eventHandler); 

        }
        else
            throw gcnew System::Exception(gcnew System::String("DotNetObject::AddEventListener() - could not find event: ") + eventType);
    }
    catch(System::Exception ^ex)
    {
        throw EcmaScript::ErrorCompletion(UStringFromString(ex->ToString()), ctxt.GetLineNo());
    }

    EcmaScript::Events::EventTargetObject::AddEventListener(ctxt, type, orListener, useCapture);
}
```

The JavaScript API I am going for is something like this:

```
    sharpBoxDll = DotNetPlugin.load("SharpBox.dll");

    myBox = sharpBoxDll.create("Box");

    myBox.onchangeName = function(ev){
        alert("Box changed name to:" + ev.name);
    }

    ev = new Event();
    ev.initEvent("changeName",true,true);
    ev.args = "newBoxName";

    myBox.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Does anyone here know if it is at all possible to create delegates with any number of params/types they way I want?

EDIT 1: Added sample code on how the DotNetEventHandler is used.

EDIT 2: Clarification: the variable ev.args is meant to provide all required arguments either as a single value or as an array ([]).

Comment: Defeating this kind of type-unsafe flexibility is pretty much the point of delegates.  Backdoors are Delegate::CreateDelegate() and Delegate::DynamicInvoke().  You'll need to think about where the arguments are going to come from, myBox.dispatchEvent() does not look like it is going to help much.

Comment: Yup, I have looked att CreateDelegate() and DynamicInvoke(). They only solve half the problem though (as far as I can tell). I need to somehow create a function which can be called no matter the argument types and that's where I am stuck ATM. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: was this topic solved in some way .. got at the same point?